# PHP If/Else statement not working

Tags: php

I have a simple search bar.

I want it to show on every page except the contact page.

Here is the code

```
function sidepanel()
{

     if ($this->request=='contact') { 

    $this->output('<div class="qa-sidepanel">');
    $this->output('</div>');

    } else
       $this->output('<div class="qa-sidepanel">');
       $this->search();
    $this->output('</div>');
}
```

On every page, it shows the search bar as it should..

However, when I go to the contact page, it shows a very messed up search bar.. but a search bar nonetheless.. Why is that? It shouldn't show one at all.

Comment: Is your question related to the popular open source Q&A platform using PHP and MySQL?

Comment: That indentation needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: Why's that? does it matter?

Comment: it's a huge pain to hit space 4 times for each line lol

Comment: when my cPanel lags like crazy every time I enter a character...

Comment: Use the `tab`, Luke.

Comment: It doesn't matter for the computer but will help on debugging code long term (for example to see missing or unpaired braces)

Comment: Yes, it definitely does matter. Also, you should not be writing code in cPanel. Use a [code editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and FTP, or better yet, [Git](https://git-scm.com/).

Comment: Look like missing a parenthesis in your code in the else part

Comment: I'll take everyone's tips here to heart! Thank you all! 

I used a PHP beautifier to fix what I've already done and from now on I'll try to code nicer..

One thing though, it's a bit of a pain uploading the new CSS/PHP files after editing them... it's easy to hit "save changes" on cPanel and refresh the website to see the changes. Does a FTP make this just as easy if not easier?

Because I can't deal with the cPanel text editor lag anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the braces on the else. Without it, only the opening of the side panel div is skipped, but the search panel and the closing of the side bar are still rendered.

```
if ($this->request=='contact') { 
    $this->output('<div class="qa-sidepanel">');
    $this->output('</div>');
} else {
    $this->output('<div class="qa-sidepanel">');
    $this->search();
    $this->output('</div>');    
}
```

or, if you tidy it up, as @AdamM suggested:

```
$this->output('<div class="qa-sidepanel">');
if ($this->request !== 'contact') { 
    $this->search();
}
$this->output('</div>');
```

Comment: Please use the === to compare strings and also why do you duplicate your code? Keep it small. If you already give an answer at least try to teach them something.

Comment: Ahah. Thank you so much.

The weird thing is, I had other If/Else statements in my PHP code that didn't have an Else bracket. No one told me you needed a bracket after the Else statement... Oddly enough, the other ones were working.

This helped me! Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't need a bracket for `else` per se. You need brackets if you have a code block of multiple statements. If it's just a single statement, you can omit the brackets (although many people feel that consistently using them makes your code more readable).